# Error while trying to do GET using Apache HttpClient in Java

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to write a Java code where I need to fetch data from a RESTful Api using Apache HttpClient.
My web server has a self signed certificate. The code I have used is as follows:

```
public class WebClientDevWrapper {

    public static HttpClient wrapClient(HttpClient base) {
        try {
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = base.getConnectionManager();
            SSLSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLSocketFactory(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
            Scheme https = new Scheme("https", 444, sslsf);
            ccm.getSchemeRegistry().register(https);
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, base.getParams());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
        HttpClient client ;
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client = WebClientDevWrapper.wrapClient(client);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://localhost/restapi");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

On running this code, I am getting the following error:
"javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for  doesn't contain CN or DNS subjectAlt"

Please help.

Comment: CN stands for "Common Name" are you sure you generated your certificate with a name?

Comment: Have you imported certificate using keytool.exe? Is it under your jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts path? Then did you provided certificate path using -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore JVM argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the SSL certificate in your JAVA. Use the below line

`<JAVA_HOME>\bin\keytool -import -v -trustcacerts
-alias [Your Alias name] -file [Your Certificate location]
-keystore [Keystore location] -keypass [Your Password]
-storepass [Your Password]`